# Условие по полю TIMESTAMP и дате в Oracle

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Никак не получается вывести все записи больше определенной даты. Запрос выводит ошибку:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

```
SELECT *
FROM application app
JOIN product_type pt ON pt.ID = app.product_type_id
WHERE DATE(created_time) > DATE('2017/11/13');
```

Может есть какой-то простой способ? Поле `created_time` имеет тип `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для приведения строки к дате можно использовать функцию [TO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) или [TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm) если нужны миллисекунды и ниже.
Для обоих функций можно указать формат даты, чтобы не зависеть от настроек NLS.
Например:

```
TO_DATE ('2017/11/13 14:10:10', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
TO_TIMESTAMP ('2017/11/13 14:10:10.123000', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

В таком варианте Ваш запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT *
FROM   application app
JOIN   product_type pt 
ON     pt.ID = app.product_type_id
WHERE  created_time > TO_DATE('2017/11/13', 'YYYY/MM/DD');
```

Обратите внимание, что в таком варианте будет создана дата "2017/11/13 00:00:00" и по такому условию вы получите строки и за 13 число(кроме самой нулевой секунды).

Если вы хотите получить все строки начиная с 14го числа, то условие будет выглядеть так:

```
WHERE created_time >= TO_DATE('2017/11/14', 'YYYY/MM/DD');
```

Answer (score 1):

Преобразование в тип даты константы, заданной в формате ISO (ANSI)

```
WHERE created_time > DATE'2017-11-13'
```

Если требуется получить результат, начиная со следующего дня, то можно написать так

```
 WHERE trunc(created_time) > DATE'2017-11-13'
```

Comment: @0xdb, дополнил.

Comment: Согласен. Интуитивно предполагал, что тип date не содержит компонент времени в отличии от timestamp. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Так хорошо. Я бы добавил ещё, что литеральная форма даты не зависит от установок формата даты/времени как преимущество, но это уже на ваше усмотрение .

Comment: Я правильно понял, что не зависимо от NLS настроек даты, в таком формате написание будет работать корректно ?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, да.

Comment: @lDrakonl  Да,  иначе же, как в ISO литерал даты не напишешь, хоть что  там в NLS стоит.

Comment: Никогда не используйте и другим не советуйте применение функций к колонкам таблицы, это убивает производительность на корню, потому как индексы не могут использоваться даже если они есть. Всегда старайтесь переписать константную часть выражения так, что бы с другой оставить саму колонку. последнее выражение пишется как created_time >= DATE'2017-11-13'+1